# Is there a way to use dual mode on a Nucleo board without using DMA?

Tags: stm32, stm32f4

For our project, we are using the STM32Nucleo446RE.
We want ADC1 and ADC2 to start sampling at the same time. We found the dual-mode, but couldn't find clear examples of how to use it.
Using the STM32CubeIDE we configured both ADCs to dual-mode.

Somewhere in the HAL-documentation, a function that seems like what we could need is called:
`HAL_ADCEx_MultiModeStart_DMA`
The description of this function is: 
Enables ADC DMA request after last transfer (Multi-ADC mode) and enables ADC peripheral.

But since we don't want to configure the DMA (because we think it's too complex at the moment) we want to know if it's possible to use dual-mode without DMA.